# Any reason for putting other visibility than private for LOG_TAG?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm currently working on some existing code containing a lot of `LOG_TAG` attributes declared with `protected` or default visibility.

I'm getting a lot of warnings due to field hiding when I declare my own `LOG_TAG`s in subclasses of these classes. That's why I'm starting to wonder why such a choice was made by previous developers.

I don't believe there is any use in exposing the `LOG_TAG` field of a class, since any child class should have its own to distinguish from its parent.

That's why I'm asking:

- do you think there is a point in using the same tag for child classes?
- if yes, do you think it is better to do so by using the parent class's field or redefining an equal (and private) `LOG_TAG` in the child class?

IMHO, all these fields should be private, and one different `LOG_TAG` for each class.

Comment: As a side, do you guys prefer to name it `TAG` or `LOG_TAG`. I'm having a hard time deciding which to stick to. I think I've seen both names show up in Android source as well. I think my OCD is itching.

Comment: @Turbo I guess you just have to be consistent within the project you work on. In the mess I'm dealing with right now, there is a mix, so I tend to change everything to `LOG_TAG` (my personal preference, because `TAG` is a bit broad). But I can understand some people might prefer `TAG` for the short length. What about `LOG`? :D

Comment: yeah, I originally started using `LOG_TAG` for the same reasons (TAG seemed too broad). But now I'm starting to like `TAG` more for the brevity. Not that I have to type more (since auto-complete in most IDEs makes that a moot point), but because it takes up less space per line, haha. Also if I ever needed more than one `TAG` in the same class it seems easier on the eyes if they were `FOO_TAG` and `BAR_TAG` as opposed to `FOO_LOG_TAG` and `BAR_LOG_TAG`. I should probably concentrate on other things than agonize over this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question, but allow me to expand on your answer. :)

It seems the point of the TAG is to accomplish primarily two things:

1. To allow filtering of LogCat output, and
2. To show which code construct (read that: Class) produced a particular piece of LogCat output.

That said, you could accomplish #1 above by sharing the TAG between parent and child classes, but not #2. So sharing `TAG`s loses (if you had, say, 3 classes that share the same `TAG` you might not always know by simple inspection of the LogCat output which class produced said output).

So to anwser your question, no, I don't see any point in using the same `TAG` for child classes. Ever. Never. Ever.

And I agree with you that the `TAG` should always be declared `private` (as well as `static final`), which would preclude a TAG declared in a parent class from being used in a child class.

I say, keep those `TAG`s `private`!

Carry on.

Comment: As a side, do you guys prefer to name it `TAG` or `LOG_TAG`. I'm having a hard time deciding which to stick to. I think I've seen both names show up in Android source as well. I think my OCD is itching.

Comment: IMHO it doesn't matter so long as the word "TAG" is in the name of the constant somewhere. That said, I prefer just TAG but can offer no firm justification other than I like it (it's probably because that's the way I learned it and have simply stuck with it). From a readability standpoint, however, pick one way of doing it, be consistent, and I think you'll be okay. Good luck.